# Problem about using ESP32 send data to MQTT broker (Raspberry Pi Node-RED)

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, esp32, sensors, node-red

I programmed an ESP32 using the Arduino IDE to interface a Max30102 sensor and measure blood oxygen level and heartbeat. I am using MQTT method to transfer data to Node-Red on Raspberry Pi. However, I ran into a problem that the data is displayed correctly on the Node-Red only when the Arduino IDE's Serial Monitor is turned on.
When closing the serial monitor, it takes about 20-30 seconds to reconnect, and the received MQTT messages can still be displayed on Node-RED. When I remove my finger from the MAX30102 sensor, "Finger please" is displayed as expected. However, when I put my finger on the sensor to detect blood oxygen and heartbeat, the reading stabilizes at blood oxygen 90 and heartbeat 0 ((beatAvg = 0, ESpO2 = 90), nothing changes. Once I open serial  Monitors again, blood oxygen and heartbeat values return to normal and start to fluctuate.

Is there a solution to this issue?

```
//---- Setup update frequency -----//
const long TEMP_updateInterval = 1000; // How long to change temp and update, 10000 = 10 sec
unsigned long TEMP_currentMillis = 0;
unsigned long TEMP_previousMillis = 0; // store last time temp update
 
#include "MAX30105.h"           //MAX3010x library
#include "heartRate.h"          //Heart rate calculating algorithm
MAX30105 particleSensor;

//計算心跳用變數
const byte RATE_SIZE = 4; //多少平均數量
byte rates[RATE_SIZE]; //心跳陣列
byte rateSpot = 0;
long lastBeat = 0; //Time at which the last beat occurred
float beatsPerMinute;
int beatAvg;

//計算血氧用變數
double avered = 0;
double aveir = 0;
double sumirrms = 0;
double sumredrms = 0;

double SpO2 = 0;
double ESpO2 = 90.0;//初始值
double FSpO2 = 0.7; //filter factor for estimated SpO2
double frate = 0.95; //low pass filter for IR/red LED value to eliminate AC component
int i = 0;
int Num = 30;//取樣30次才計算1次
#define FINGER_ON 7000    //紅外線最小量（判斷手指有沒有上）
#define MINIMUM_SPO2 90.0 //血氧最小量

int WIFILED = 5;
/*
  SimpleMQTTClient.ino
  The purpose of this exemple is to illustrate a simple handling of MQTT and Wifi connection.
  Once it connects successfully to a Wifi network and a MQTT broker, it subscribe to a topic and send a message to it.
  It will also send a message delayed 5 seconds later.
*/
 
#include "EspMQTTClient.h"
 
EspMQTTClient client(
    "---------",     // Wi-Fi AP name
    "-------", // Wi-Fi Password
    "---------", // MQTT Broker server ip/ Using What is my IP
    "yat",                  // Broker user name; Can be omitted if not needed
    "--------",                  // Broker password; Can be omitted if not needed
    "MAX30102",      // Client name that uniquely identify your device
    1883                 // The MQTT port, default to 1883. this line can be omitted
);
 
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    //Start DH11 sensor
      //change
  if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) //Use default I2C port, 400kHz speed
  {
    Serial.println("Cant find MAX30102");
    while (1);
  }
    //
  byte ledBrightness = 0x7F; //suggest=127, Options: 0=Off to 255=50mA
  byte sampleAverage = 4; //Options: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32
  byte ledMode = 2; //Options: 1 = Red only(心跳), 2 = Red + IR(血氧)
  int sampleRate = 800; //Options: 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 1600, 3200
  int pulseWidth = 215; //Options: 69, 118, 215, 411
  int adcRange = 16384; //Options: 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384

  particleSensor.setup(ledBrightness, sampleAverage, ledMode, sampleRate, pulseWidth, adcRange); //Configure sensor with these settings
  particleSensor.enableDIETEMPRDY();

  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeRed(0x0A); //Turn Red LED to low to indicate sensor is running
  particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeGreen(0); //Turn off Green LED
 
    pinMode(WIFILED, OUTPUT);
    // Optionnal functionnalities of EspMQTTClient :
    client.enableDebuggingMessages(); // Enable debugging messages sent to serial output
    //client.enableHTTPWebUpdater();  // Enable the web updater. User and password default to values of MQTTUsername and MQTTPassword. These can be overrited with enableHTTPWebUpdater("user", "password").
    //client.enableLastWillMessage("TestClient/lastwill", "I am going offline"); // You can activate the retain flag by setting the third parameter to true
}
 
// This function is called once everything is connected (Wifi and MQTT)
// WARNING : YOU MUST IMPLEMENT IT IF YOU USE EspMQTTClient
void onConnectionEstablished()
{
    // Subscribe to "mytopic/test" and display received message to Serial
    client.subscribe("message/hello", [](const String &payload)
                     { Serial.println(payload); });
 
    // Subscribe to "mytopic/wildcardtest/#" and display received message to Serial
    //client.subscribe("mytopic/wildcardtest/#", [](const String &topic, const String &payload)
    //                 { Serial.println("(From wildcard) topic: " + topic + ", payload: " + payload); });
 
    // Publish a message to "mytopic/test"
    client.publish("studio/spo2", "Let's go!"); // You can activate the retain flag by setting the third parameter to true
    client.publish("studio/bpm", "Let's go!"); // You can activate the retain flag by setting the third parameter to true

    
     digitalWrite(WIFILED, HIGH);
    // Execute delayed instructions
    //client.executeDelayed(5 * 1000, []()
    //                      { client.publish("mytopic/wildcardtest/test123", "This is a message sent 5 seconds later"); });
}
 
 
 
void loop()
{
 
    TEMP_currentMillis = millis();
    if(TEMP_currentMillis - TEMP_previousMillis >= TEMP_updateInterval){
        TEMP_previousMillis = TEMP_currentMillis;
          }
 

 long irValue = particleSensor.getIR();    //Reading the IR value it will permit us to know if there's a finger on the sensor or not



 
  //put the finger or  not
  if (irValue > FINGER_ON ) {
    
    //check heart beat
    if (checkForBeat(irValue) == true) {
     
      Serial.print("Bpm="); Serial.println(beatAvg);//
      client.publish("studio/bpm", String(beatAvg));
      long delta = millis() - lastBeat;//計算心跳差
      lastBeat = millis();
      beatsPerMinute = 60 / (delta / 1000.0);//cal bpm
      if (beatsPerMinute < 255 && beatsPerMinute > 20) {
        //bpm must between 20-255
        rates[rateSpot++] = (byte)beatsPerMinute; //save bpm
        rateSpot %= RATE_SIZE;
        beatAvg = 0;// cal avg
        for (byte x = 0 ; x < RATE_SIZE ; x++) beatAvg += rates[x];
        beatAvg /= RATE_SIZE;
      }
    }

    // detect spo2
    uint32_t ir, red ;
    double fred, fir;
    particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor, read up to 3 samples
    if (particleSensor.available()) {
      i++;
      ir = particleSensor.getFIFOIR(); //red IR
      red = particleSensor.getFIFORed(); //read red
      //Serial.println("red=" + String(red) + ",IR=" + String(ir) + ",i=" + String(i));
      fir = (double)ir;//change to double
      fred = (double)red;//change to double
      aveir = aveir * frate + (double)ir * (1.0 - frate); //average IR level by low pass filter
      avered = avered * frate + (double)red * (1.0 - frate);//average red level by low pass filter
      sumirrms += (fir - aveir) * (fir - aveir);//square sum of alternate component of IR level
      sumredrms += (fred - avered) * (fred - avered); //square sum of alternate component of red level

      if ((i % Num) == 0) {
        double R = (sqrt(sumirrms) / aveir) / (sqrt(sumredrms) / avered);
        SpO2 = -23.3 * (R - 0.4) + 100;
        ESpO2 = FSpO2 * ESpO2 + (1.0 - FSpO2) * SpO2;//low pass filter
        if (ESpO2 <= MINIMUM_SPO2) ESpO2 = MINIMUM_SPO2; //indicator for finger detached
        if (ESpO2 > 100) ESpO2 = 99.9;
        //Serial.print(",SPO2="); Serial.println(ESpO2);
        sumredrms = 0.0; sumirrms = 0.0; SpO2 = 0;
        i = 0;
      }
      particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample
    }
    
    //display display in serial
    Serial.print("Bpm:" + String(beatAvg));
    client.publish("studio/bpm", String(beatAvg));
    //BPM over 30, show SPO2
    if (beatAvg > 30){ 
     Serial.println(",SPO2:" + String(ESpO2)); 
    client.publish("studio/spo2", String(ESpO2));   
    }

    
    else {
      Serial.println(",SPO2:" + String(ESpO2)); 
      client.publish("studio/spo2", String(ESpO2));
      }


  }
  //if no finger, display"Finger Please"
  else {
    //clear heart beat data
    for (byte rx = 0 ; rx < RATE_SIZE ; rx++) rates[rx] = 0;
    beatAvg = 0; rateSpot = 0; lastBeat = 0;
    //clear SPO2 data
    avered = 0; aveir = 0; sumirrms = 0; sumredrms = 0;
    SpO2 = 0; ESpO2 = 90.0;
    //顯示Finger Please
      Serial.println("Finger Please");        
       //Publish
       client.publish("studio/spo2", String("Finger Please"));
       client.publish("studio/bpm", String("Finger Please"));
  }

 
        // Here is how to subscribe
        //client.subscribe("message/hello", [](const String &payload) { Serial.println(payload); });
  
 
    client.loop();
}
```